# Append error messages to form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

After a jQuery post of my form data, I get a JSON object back. When the form isn't valid, the status is set to "error" and messages are appended where the error exactly occured.

This is my response (fetched from Firebug console)

```
"status":"error",
"messages":{
    "email":{
        "emailAddressInvalidFormat":"'asd' is no valid email address in the basic format local-part@hostname"
    }
 }
```

The insertion of the post when the form was valid is working perfectly. Now I use this code to add error messages when a form failed:

```
$.each(data.messages, function(element, errors) {
    var ul = $("<ul>").attr("class", "errors");
    $.each(errors, function(name, message) {
        ul.append($("<li>").val(message));
    });

    $("#" + element).after(ul);
});
```

I notice that element and message are fine (checked with `console.log()`). I think it goes wrong due to the (second) loop, because at other places this similar piece of code works ok. I am sure the html isn't inserted into the DOM, I checked that also with Firebug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

val() method is used to set and retrieve information from form tags. Use the text() method instead of it:

`ul.append($("<li>").text(message));`